# How to check Oracle Client installed on any system (windows or unix) through JAVA

Tags: java, oracle

i want to check if Oracle Client is installed on any system(windows or unix) through java.
Can anyone give me any idea how to do this.. i saw few posts of invoking "tnsping.exe" but 1st i am not sure how to invoke it from java and 2nd .exe exists for windows, not sure what to check in unix for same.

Comment: Short of searching through all files on the harddisk (and even then it might not be correct) I don't think there is a way. Remember there is also an "instantclient" which does not need to be "installed" - and there could be multiple copies of the client on the system as well.

Comment: Scanning through disk is too long process i guess..